# vue js checkbox, pass a json object as value to model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is it possible to pass a Json Object as value on a checkbox 
I have multiple checkboxes like below...
selectedUsers is an array that contains the selected values... id like to end up with a json array like [{"userid": "12345"}, {"userid": "54321"}]

```
<input
  :id="`checkbox` + index" v-model="selectedUsers"
  :value="{"userId": user.userId}"
  @change="selectUsers"
```

The above gives me a parsing error
Parsing error: unexpected-character-in-attribute-name.

I am able to pass an object like this

```
  :value="{userId: user.userId}"
```

Is there a clever way to achieve what i want here?

Comment: So you want to pass `{"userId": user.userId}` as a string?

Comment: so user.id is dynamic value.... so i want to pass for example {"userId": "123ABC"}... selectedUsers is an array... im trying to create a json array

Comment: Your parsing error is because you are using the same type of quotes: `:value="{"userId": user.userId}"` is interpreted as `:value="{"` and `userId": user.userId}"`, the second of which is invalid.  Use different quotation marks instead: `:value="{'userId': user.userId}"'

Comment: Of course that is entirely equivalent to just not putting `userId` in quotes at all, which is what you did on the second one.... so, what exactly are you wanting to do?  In what way precisely is `:value="{userId: user.userId}"` not doing what you want?

Comment: so im basically trying to construct a json array that can use in an api call... i updated my question above...  if i use :value="{'userId': user.userId}"' the value still gets set as {userId: "1234"} in the array ...

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want you can create an object and pass that to the value as below.

```
  <input
  :id="`checkbox` + index" v-model="selectedUsers"
  :value="details"
  @change="selectUsers">

  data: {
    details:{
    user:'userid'
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry probably wasnt explained well, so its a series of checkboxes... selectedUsers above is an array... and when a checkbox is selected i'd like to pass json object to it...

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/150amowf/7/. In this the v-model isChecked is populated with the value being passed.

Comment: yeah that works for one binding, but not for multiple

Comment: @blu10 I made a small change to Rhiddhi's comment, https://jsfiddle.net/w6vz3e4q/1/ I believe this is what you're after?

Comment: @jordan I have updated you forget to change the variable name.https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/vjm7ck5z/

Answer (score 0):

Call a method and pass it the user id:

```xml
<input
  :id="`checkbox` + index" v-model="selectedUsers"
  :value="userIdObj(user.userId)"
  @change="selectUsers">
```

And then in the component's methods declaration:

```js
methods: {
    userIdObj(id) {
        return '{ "userId": ' + id + ' }';
    }
}
```